# Print conditional with filter in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to print a value of variable depending of value of other variable. I am using angular js.

My code to print in view is:

```
{{w.date == 0 ? w.eventIndex : w.date | date: 'medium'}}
```

I need apply date filter only for w.date, but not for w.eventIndex. I can take other way without problem, but I would like keep this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
{{w.date == 0 ? w.eventIndex : (w.date | date: 'medium')}}
```

That should apply the filter only to w.date.